# Transpose not defined for N-d objects in Octave

Tags: multidimensional-array, octave

I am running a script file(.m) which can produce lots of csv file from [Table.csv](https://www.mediafire.com/?i13bsqi677wnmdc) based on the Table in [Test.txt](https://www.mediafire.com/?b6s7um06wk8vz4q):

```
function array()
fid=fopen('Test.txt')
A=[]
for i=1:800
  data=str2num(fgetl(fid))
  A=horzcat(A,data)
end
fclose(fid)
A=reshape(A,[30,40,20])
LO=[115.0,118.0,119.0,119.5,120.0,120.1,120.2,120.3,120.4,120.5,120.6,120.7,120.8,120.9,121.0,121.1,121.2,121.3,121.4,121.5,121.6,121.7,121.8,121.9,122.0,122.5,123.0,124.0,125.0,130.0]
LA=[15.0,21.0,21.5,21.8,22.0,22.1,22.2,22.3,22.4,22.5,22.6,22.7,22.8,22.9,23.0,23.1,23.2,23.3,23.4,23.5,23.6,23.7,23.8,23.9,24.0,24.1,24.2,24.3,24.4,24.5,24.6,24.7,24.8,24.9,25.0,25.2,25.4,26.0,27.0,30.0]
H=[-10.0,0,2.0,4.0,6.0,9.0,13.0,17.0,21.0,25.0,30.0,35.0,50.0,70.0,90.0,110.0,140.0,170.0,200.0,700.0]
Table=csvread('Table.csv')
row=size(Table,1)
[str,maxarray]=computer
[LAX,LOY,HZ]=meshgrid(LA,LO,H)
for i=5129:2:row
%{
[LOS,IXS]=min(abs(LO(:)-P(1,1)))
[LAS,IYS]=min(abs(LA(:)-P(1,2)))
[HS,IZS]=min(abs(H(:)-P(2,3)))
[LOD,IXD]=min(abs(LO(:)-P(2,1)))
[LAD,IYD]=min(abs(LA(:)-P(2,2)))
[HD,IZD]=min(abs(H(:)-P(2,3)))
%}
LOD=round(abs((Table(i+1,1)-Table(i,1)))/0.001)
LAD=round(abs((Table(i+1,2)-Table(i,2)))/0.001)
if Table(i,3)<Table(i+1,3)
    HD=round(abs(Table(i,3)-200)*10)
    PH=Table(i,3)
else
    HD=round(abs(Table(i+1,3)-200)*10)
    PH=Table(i+1,3)
end
if LOD*LAD*HD>237*430*2011
continue
else
    LOL=linspace(Table(i+1,1),Table(i,1),LOD)
    if Table(i+1,2)>Table(i,2)
        LAL=linspace(Table(i+1,2),Table(i,2)-0.001,LAD+1)
    else
        LAL=linspace(Table(i+1,2),Table(i,2)+0.001,LAD+1)
    end
    HL=linspace(PH,200,HD)
    [LALX,LOLY,HLZ]=meshgrid(LAL,LOL,HL)
    clear B LAL LOL HL
    B=interp3(LAX,LOY,HZ,A,LALX,LOLY,HLZ)
    clear LALX LOLY HLZ
    TableName=sprintf('Table%d_%d.csv',Table(i,4),i)
    csvwrite(TableName,B)
    TableDimName=sprintf('TableDim%d_%d.txt',Table(i,4),i)
    fileID = fopen(TableDimName,'w');
    fprintf(fileID,'%d %d %d\n',LOD,LAD+1,HD);
    fclose(fileID);
end
end
end
```

In Matlab, it compiles successfully without any warnings. While in Octave, it shows the following error:

```
error: transpose not defined for N-d objects
error: evaluating argument list element number 3
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.2/m/io/dlmwrite.m at line 193, column 7
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.8.2/m/io/csvwrite.m at line 35, column 3
warning: broken pipe
error:   /home/r02036/HuygenT/TableII/array.m at line 50, column 9
```

I know it is related to the problem of wrongly using transpose for multi-dimensional array, but here I don't use any of them. Can anyone give me a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: your error is coming from line 50 of `array.m` when calling `csvwrite.m` but the array function you pasted has only 48 lines and csvwrite is at line 41. Something's not right. Did you *really* paste your code. Enter debug mode right before calling `csvwrite` and check the status (place `keyboard` command on the line above). The error may be something before that but you will have to debug it yourself.

Comment: Sorry for posing wrong code. I have updated it to the right one. However, I cannot find the difference from the old one and the code can be executed in Matlab successfully

Comment: `B=interp3(...)` probably is a 3-dimensional matrix. No idea how Matlab writes this to a csv but apparently this is not implemented the same way in octave. I suggest trying something like `csvwrite(TableName, B(:,:))`.